# Pillow - Image's putdata function returning black

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to change a greyscale image to color, with colors the user wants.

```
newPic = []
for x in sequence_of_pixels:
    minNum = gs[min(range(len(gs)), key = lambda i:abs(gs[i]-x))]
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        
        if minNum == gs[i]:
            color = colors[i]

    newPic.append(color)

#this fuction is my probem
img.putdata(newPic)
img.save('tester.png')
```

I don't know what is wrong, the newPic list is updated correctly with the new pixel colors. Just when I run the putdata it returns black

Comment: Please provide a full [mre]. Has `img` mode `L`? If so, does it have mode `L` even after applying RGB data? That most likely will cause issues, I guess.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I got it to work with: img1 = Image.new("RGB", (img.size), (255, 255, 255))
        
        img1.putdata(newPic)